# Is there a mathematical way to find the lattice points in a crystal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

In my solid state physics class we need to be able to determine the number of lattice points per cell of various Bravais lattices. For example, the orthorhombic which has 4 lattice points per cell. I usually can figure out how to find the number by picturing what multiple lattices would look like next to each other and counting, but is there a more mathematical approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are referring to the Face-centered orthorhombic, when you cite 4 lattice points, since the other three orthorhombic Bravais lattices have conventional cells with less than four atoms.

In my opinion, the simplest way of counting the number of lattice points is to consider each internal point with weight $1$, points on the external surfaces with weight $1/2$, and points on the vertices  with weight $1/8$.